# WHoosh (full text search) index problem

Tags: django, whoosh

iam having the following problem with whoosh full text search engine.

1.After syncdb i am creating the intial index from the database objects.

2.it is working fine.I can able to search the data and see the results.

3.after that in one of my view i have added another document (via signals) to the index (during a request --response)

4.that' it from then onwards i could not able to search any data , for which i have successfully found results before adding new document (before step 3)

```
ix = storage.open_index()
writer = ix.writer()
writer.add_document(.............)
```

I have tried  hard to resolve but i could not.

Any ideas on how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Any one interested in the above problem
Please follow the below thread.

http://groups.google.com/group/whoosh/browse_thread/thread/9f2cd0d45d88fe22

It happened  because of a bug in whoosh package and it was fixed.

Now ever thing is working fine.